# How can a TypeScript forEach, infer the types of a union, and change the return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

We want to take a document type and mutate some of it's fields and then return the new document with the new types. We want to determine the fields to mutate based on an array of values (`collectionDataFields` in the example below).

```
type AllDocuments = {
    __typename: 'cat'
    a: '123',
    b: '123',
    z: 'xyz'
} | {
    __typename: 'dog'
    a: '123',
    c: '123',
    z: 'xyz'
}

const collectionDateFields = {
    cat: ['a', 'b'],
    dog: ['a', 'c']
} as const

export const useStringsToNums = (document: AllDocuments) => {
  const dateFields = collectionDateFields[document.__typename]

  dateFields.forEach((field) => {
    document[field] = parseInt(document[field])
  })
  return document
}
```

In the example, `dateFields` is typed as `readonly ["a", "b"] | readonly ["a", "c"]` but the individual `field` comes in as `any`.

The `document` is returned as the `AllDocuments` even though we want it to have the field with the changed type (as a `number`).

[TS Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAIgewMYFcC2EB2wDOUAvFAN4BQUVUA%20jaJDgIbYBcUA5Kk8B5dU3YcAjACYAzBwA0-KgCMhYyeQC%20UAD5lZteuFwsIQgCbIA5n2pRBnJdO2pFEvivLlUyHPmBR3CCKmAASw9EHggAMUCIOCNCEgpLbmB2AG0OJmlOOQ4AXRlLE1NU9MyuXNUrQndPYFcIAA8wZAAnb2qvKHR8CFDgCHwAFWQAGXR6j2IoAAoTDGw8dngkNCxcAgBKYgA%20LSp27yMwyOjYyd84fyCQo6iY-BTZ1bwAOjoGfWwc1ypDvuO754AMxaAFEmKgABZTKaA25GTZEHYJaiPebAFKwk45SZgJjNboASTwMxWaIxcJy634KipVGaEGA6GaOCgqLWqnIQA)

Edit: For an example of the usage, I would do something like this:

```
useStringsToNums({
    __typename: 'cat'
    a: '123',
    b: '123',
    z: 'xyz'
})
```

In this case, the function turns the properties that match `__typename: 'cat'` into numbers (with the `parseInt`).

Comment: Are you defining types for a/b/z as literal strings? Can you provide an example call to useDatesToLuxon and what you expect to come out?

Comment: (You can't mutate types in TS; create a new object instead.)  This runs into a problem with what I call *correlated union types* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). I've spent a bit of time trying to get something *sort of* type safe from the compiler, but the [closest I got](//tsplay.dev/Nn6GBN) isn't useful enough to be worth the complexity. Assuming you don't want [redundancy](//tsplay.dev/Wyv02w), then you'll need to [assert around it](//tsplay.dev/Wvp9QN).  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer. Let me know.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAIgewMYFcC2EB2wDOUAvAFBRQA+UA3mefQPoOiQ4CG2AXFAOSpvAeAbjr0obbjwCMAJgDMw0fQBGk2QpFiAvnSq0x5Ji1wcIkgCbIA5ooPi182wdQONSrSJKpkOfMCiWqMQ0dEbgJly8-IIANHQSvDIyPHHkqrxyCnEeJF4+flDeCBCowACWPogCEABiZRBw5oREIeTR3ADaPGwpvMo8ALqpAdad3b18g9nihN6+wJ5zBej4EFXAEPgAKsgAMugAHj7BABSBWLjA3Gw4IACUxAB8rYX5-ubVdQ1NwUVwJeVKp96o18B1ztg8AA6MKsUwDTQBYHffBQgBmyAATgBRNioAAWJxOaJB5geRGe+noEMuHRJ3wGwTAbExqwAkngzmgLng6aSBndEVpBXRMRBgOhMTgRhhIQsSDk8r5kP8oXBrCcVmtqts9ocfFzUHcRUA

Comment: I also set "noImplicitAny": false

Comment: @olore The types are literal strings. I added an example of how I want to call the function.

Comment: @jcalz That looks like what I want, thanks for making those. I would happily accept an answer if you wanted to make one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We want to take a document type and mutate some of its fields

If you have an object of a type where there is a `string`-valued property at some key, you can't assign a `number` to that same property without the compiler complaining.  One of the motivations behind TypeScript is to add a strong static type system to JavaScript, and assigning a `number` to something which is supposed to be a `string` goes against that:

```
function doSomething(doc: AllDocuments) {
  doc.a = 123; // error! Type '123' is not assignable to type '"123"'    
}
```

You *could* just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress these errors:

```
function doSomething(doc: AllDocuments) {
  doc.a = 123; // error! Type '123' is not assignable to type '"123"'    
}
```

But all this does is make things worse in the long run.  TypeScript does not model arbitrary type mutations, only [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).    There's no way to say that after calling `doSomething(doc)`, the type of `doc` has changed so that a former `string` property is now a `number`. By asserting that a `number` is a `string`, you are lying to the compiler, and you are liable to encounter errors at runtime:

```
const doc: AllDocuments = { __typename: "cat", a: "123", b: "123" };
doSomething(doc);
try {
  doc.a.toUpperCase(); // compiles but has runtime error:
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // doc.a.toUpperCase is not a function    
}
```

Assuming you don't want to widen those property types from `"123"` to something that can handle both `"123"` and `123`, then it's probably a better idea to just create a new object of the type you're looking for, and treat the original object as immutable:

```
function doSomethingElse(doc: AllDocuments) {
  return { ...doc, a: 123 }
}
const newDoc = doSomethingElse(doc);
/* const newDoc: {
  a: number;
  __typename: 'cat';
  b: '123';
 } | {
  a: number;
  __typename: 'dog';
  c: '123';
 } */
console.log(newDoc.a.toFixed(2)); // "123.00"
```

For the rest of this answer I will use this approach.

---

---

Now for the rest of your question.  You are running into a problem with what I've been calling *correlated union types* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

In the following code:

```
  const dateFields = collectionDateFields[document.__typename]
  dateFields.forEach((field: "a" | "b" | "c") => {
    document[field] // oops
  })
```

even if we annotate `field` with the type we expect it to be, the compiler is unable to see that `document` has a key named `field`.  The type of `document` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of two distinct types, and the type of `dateField` is also a union of two distinct types, and the type of `field` is also a union.  But the compiler sees these three unions as *independent* or *uncorrelated*.  As far as it understands, `document.__typename` could be `"cat"` and yet `field` could be `"c"`.  *You* know that this is impossible, but the compiler loses the thread.

---

Sometimes it's possible to refactor code to avoid the correlated-union problem.  Unfortunately, despite spending some time trying to get something *sort of* type safe from the compiler, the closest I could get isn't useful enough to be worth the complexity:

```
const useDatesToLuxon = <T extends AllDocuments['__typename']>(
  document: Extract<AllDocuments, { __typename: T }>
) => {
  type Fields = (typeof collectionDateFields)[T][number];
  const dateFields: readonly Fields[] = collectionDateFields[document.__typename]
  const doc = document as Record<Fields, string>;
  const newDoc = {} as Record<Fields, number>;
  dateFields.forEach((field) => {
    newDoc[field] = parseInt(doc[field])
  })
  const ret = { ...(document as Omit<typeof document, Fields>), ...newDoc };
  type Ret = typeof ret;
  return ret as { [K in keyof Ret]: Ret[K] }
}
```

That's a lot of type juggling, and in the end it only works for arguments known to be a single member of the `AllDocuments` union:

```
const r = useDatesToLuxon({ __typename: "cat", a: "123", b: "123" });
/* const r: {
    __typename: 'cat';
    a: number;
    b: number;
} */
console.log(r); // as expected
```

If you try to call it on an object whose type is only known to be the full `AllDocuments` union, you get the wrong output type:

```
function butWait(doc: AllDocuments) {
  const u = useDatesToLuxon(doc);
  /* const u: {
    __typename: "cat" | "dog";
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
    } */
  // UGH, no, that's not the type we want; we cannot programmatically *distribute* the 
  // behavior of useDatesToLuxon across the union members of AllDocuments
}
```

So let's give up on such refactoring.

---

There isn't a great solution to correlated unions.  One way you can work around the problem is by using redundant code, breaking your code block into several identical chunks where the compiler can use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to go through the different cases:

```
export const useDatesToLuxon = (document: AllDocuments) => {
  switch (document.__typename) {
    case "cat": {
      const dateFields = collectionDateFields[document.__typename]
      const temp = {} as Record<typeof dateFields[number], number>
      dateFields.forEach((field) => {
        temp[field] = parseInt(document[field])
      })
      return { ...document, ...temp }
    }
    case "dog": {
      const dateFields = collectionDateFields[document.__typename]
      const temp = {} as Record<typeof dateFields[number], number>
      dateFields.forEach((field) => {
        temp[field] = parseInt(document[field])
      })
      return { ...document, ...temp }
    }
  }
}
```

This works very well, and is quite type safe.  In the `"cat"` case and in the `"dog"` case, the compiler knows exactly what is happening.  But such redundancy doesn't scale.  It would be nice if you could ask the compiler to *pretend* you had written such redundant code, as I asked for in [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051), but you can't.

---

My general recommendation for this situation is to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to loosen the type checking inside the implementation of your function.  This shifts the burden of maintaining type safety away from the compiler (which can't do it properly here) onto you, so you need to be careful.

Here's one possible way to do it.  First, let's compute the type we expect to come out of your function:

```
type CollectionDateFields = typeof collectionDateFields;

type ConvertedDocuments = { 
  [D in AllDocuments as D['__typename']]: { 
    [K in keyof D]: K extends 
      CollectionDateFields[D['__typename']][number] ? number : D[K] 
} }[keyof CollectionDateFields]
```

That's using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) to iterate over each member of `AllDocuments` and converting the relevant properties mentioned in `collectionDateFields` to `number`.  You can verify that it's correct:

```
/* type ConvertedDocuments = {
__typename: "cat";
a: number;
b: number;
} | {
__typename: "dog";
a: number;
c: number;
} */
```

Now we can give `useDatesToLuxon` a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) call signature describing what it does:

```
function useDatesToLuxon<D extends AllDocuments>(
  document: D
): Extract<ConvertedDocuments, Pick<D, '__typename'>>
```

That's a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function which can turn the whole `AllDocuments` union into the whole `ConvertedDocuments` union, as well as turning any subtype into the analogous output type.  Now for the implementation:

```
function useDatesToLuxon(_document: AllDocuments): ConvertedDocuments {
  // let's just pretend it's one of the members of the union
  const document = _document as Extract<AllDocuments, { __typename: "cat" }>
  const dateFields = collectionDateFields[document.__typename]
  const temp = {} as Record<typeof dateFields[number], number>
  dateFields.forEach((field) => {
    temp[field] = parseInt(document[field])
  })
  return { ...document, ...temp }
}
```

Here the easiest assertion for me to make is to just pretend that `document` is one of the members of the union.  It's not technically true, but it suppresses the complaints from the compiler.  We just have to be careful that we've implemented it properly.

And now to test it:

```
const r = useDatesToLuxon({ __typename: "cat", a: "123", b: "123" });
/* const r: {
    __typename: 'cat';
    a: number;
    b: number;
} */
console.log(r); // as expected

function andThen(doc: AllDocuments) {
  const u = useDatesToLuxon(doc);
  /* {
    __typename: "cat";
    a: number;
    b: number;
  } | {
    __typename: "dog";
    a: number;
    c: number;
  } */

}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkgC4CeMyAghhgCID28ArpMCVEgLx5HFIB9AeUqhIALiQBydCSl9iISVICMAJgDMUgDQKkAI2XqtfAL5IAPr36DhFCGIjKAJgwDm8m0unGde+EaankimhMTwDMBQJEgRtBDwJACWkXQgJBAAYkkQGM6cPAQ2spIA2lIgOtL6UgC6ujaubmUVVTJ1ZkggnBFRJIR8AGbMwIkpwEiuAMoMkCQAFknAbgAUrgFINPRMrA4cAJTW-OsAdCDcSMYA3EgA9LdIEABOTwxPAIRIACr2PkFISU4wAYMW6UCSblA+gwyBIDFIvykACJjEjgsRTuceMYupwQMAyDd7kgGABrEBkbQGZgxBYOMxhWKRaKTJiSLaMFhsDgXXC2EQOcBOJBI2RIqneFGacUGSRSjRIkJXPjTWYQBZLVbrfbK4gkJ5kI4YphnE5wgCqMEoTwAwt0ICsdXcHhEwDAkjDOPoaUh5t0kE8RslII8Xm9xJ1ZPB5kgVhBDkV+L0oAwYScMO4407iZizQxLda7VBkICkMDQUhhqNkpEbAyhiMxrXVXNFssAKIYYtrNmbWic3bsKAJvRPdXMJ4TPknGfrCWSHGhYhLpl9MsQADunIuLfVbbcne72t1dwAVKuWcBN5zJInFJJgKx9M8T8QhALHMpZFJX7K-lpX3MKw7y6B8nxfPR33sT9pCaH9-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-MC4LQpyvJnv0mwRaYbKItxpA4CeYsAEl2B7eBDdysradKkrRIDdVeSQGcTmt1TmYAeTAJIzp+v79vYKlgZ0-YqQ9-X4CVV7fjZmIeCDl2SEFscSAnCYM+ZvlSgAaQBCZSQgMhftZ9VakkROC7yldl0ZOmWSeC5+sGmSGFG8bgBWG7Kc24VRXSGVJVRKlDBFVFSt-W5z2dp5bxKt9+5gmR0ngh37zlqGIM3v9Ieh38ULQnqokw7DVieKjmYEyhElIxvK0bQnqRIAB1EAA+t9TltU7T0qFn1VuxZ24jTGpEa2OoSqz0AcwRee9bpCjlGKSwIomhIkFlvA+u9N4T2wU8TBsQwI7wIUvEISBULQIeOaNqAAJKkwIqQLHXkCEEpB5iwl+BuZAG58RpyQNw2I+Jywm1eG4E6YAwDpCSOgWghpTzOEBFJb0GRzx0iQFQgwEA-QADcUgt3Lm3EyHcu61gQK8KAnB1EjHGEgSAJDODlwuitIc5VGSVWYkKVitU2bOBGMZdg+lb7CVgSA4xYDu4XC9tyH+A4tI6wAVADcAdozKTJhTD8QoRx73QMWRKw94F70AYjUyKsLj40BsrcypMXHk0QdTMhTdaQ8RgLycWnBJYc0minEp2N8H1G3tDR6RTJhVPyGrJ4QVoyawigkxp-AMhultnkY2psLZWxDiQZZzhaj2yKaYPZe8M5ZzwO7WcZMo4zkWa0+utNbnFHtGg9wSJCk5IRmMiyqYrKEyBiTTZGToIeXmc7a5bTmadOlt0+w5dekk36Qw+WwyimwpVhMqZIUwqzN0rrTe1ztmrJAGbCAlsSDRKylrHZhzN4HPmccycpyPabMuWaFpIQyH3LZTYSq9ZPGQG8dQSxzwMjOG6gs34NovkE3GL8spydoV-QqT8j5yo9BvQlcAHRQrSJxNWm7UodAi5LR1UOZmdB1oryFHUKupyC6GpLmXP6dBrWFwEvNfIJUJUAyVUjFW+rzWZK2rUcG-SkAAH5BnPCQJIM1+c64hFKPa8unrvnSo+Z5PQMC1WRE1U8YVxqeSFEghaiQ+SSAYL0N4fBv48HyyPqgkC9TB7oN-JW2tCEI2kK5RQtCegqzWT6mEjIJjwHAEmga11DhFrOL-jtTZ0b9iHWOqdSa6qc15rJlAKk7EZGkjHVSKQjapA6SRcQPtL8jFDoiRAgQc6jUboXUgVdWrnD5s4AA4kMI5CcAAFbiRiDADOk6ARfpJFeEkf11H2Oho4iDHC+rAHGE7BGTMeA3qZv6I6+pl3Tq0tdfkgKS1DzLSEE9Bl6YfPKZKypPrqn-MbTTWmILWVi3BezSFPSPkQ3lgM-BpHvI0fGQFSZGtMUOTmXvPFFKCVEpJWS9g+KqXLkU6nE505zm1OZaC25HiyPN2AQNcJncR293w1TQeYp5yT2lOPOUU8Dkzznr1BeOLl4BuFGvOQhDW0kMITWnz5Vu3+GZOfDMl9r7+lvgTB+vbn62PxM4L4HCe7rFifenFztmD6dAUZ7ukDBYwIAa5gj5nh5eeIYfMhfmKtduAmQxtcpm1kO89VzeGwq0BcoW4+spggA)

Comment: Thanks for adding such a good explanation. I understand most of it but am not sure exactly why `number` is used when indexing the `collectionDateFields` here `type Fields = (typeof collectionDateFields)[T][number];`. I thought `T` matched cat/dog and am not sure why `number` would be used for the resulting array?

Comment: `(typeof collectionDateFields)[T]` is an array type... to get the *element* type for that array, we want to index into the array with a key of type `number`.  Hence the `[number]` index at the end.   Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks for the extra information!